# JWT validated even token used in another browser

Tags: angular, laravel, authentication, jwt

I have a project set up (Frontend Angular) and Backend (Laravel 5.6), I made a api call to by backend to login using JWT ( for authentication ) in case of invalid crdentials error message was returned, This seems ok but in case of correct credentials token is returned which had to be saved at client side (using localStorage) What i copy then token saved in the localstorage and tried to login from different machine and different browser also from both case user was logged in and redirected to dashboard.

I have to Restrict the user to login and redirect How can i achieve that am i doing something wrong?

Comment: I didn't understand what you did. Did you copy the token from one machine to another ?

Comment: That's the intended behavior of both session cookies and localstorage token.

Comment: This article could help you to understand JWT token : https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: @JEY Yes exactly i did the same, i copied the token and tried on another machine and also on same machine but with different browser in both case i was successfully logged in because token at server end is not expired yet.

Comment: That exactly what should happen. As suggested by @JoelJoseph read more about jwt

Comment: @JEY So i can create the web app with this approach ? I have read the jwt and my token is correctly generated and expiring on time but only issue is that i have to secure my token at client end.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the major issue with security tokens: if an attacker intercept the token, he can use it from another browser or application. That is why it is highly recommended to set a very short lifetime (`exp` claim)

But hopefully, [RFC8471](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8471), [RFC8472](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8472) and [RFC8473](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8473) have recently been approved. These specifications allow to bind the token to the HTTPS or HTTP connection making the attack described above practically impossible.

At the time of writing, this feature is not widely adopted by browsers. [EDGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/token-binding/introducing-token-binding) supports it (draft version), no move for [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1363987) or Chrome.